# Getting Typerror: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python-3.x, list

Given question -    Given a list of 10 numbers, find the average of all such numbers which is a multiple of 3

```
num = []
newlist = []

for i in range(1, 11):
    num.append(input())


for i in num:
    if i%3==0:
        newlist.append(i)

length = len(newlist)

total = sum(newlist)

average = total/length

print(average)
```

Getting this type error below at line 9 i.e. if i%3==0

not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: In Python3 `input()` has the same functionality as `raw_input()` in python2.7. That is, it returns the input from the users as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input()` returns a *string*, so `i%3` will actually perform [`printf`-style *string formatting*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting). Since your input doesn't have any formatting specifiers, but the `%` operator's right operand is not empty, you get the error, because you attempted to format a sting that doesn't have enough formatting specifiers.

To solve this, convert your input to integers:

```
num.append(int(input()))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `num.append(input())`, the value of `input()` is a *string*. You need to first convert that to an `int` and handle any possible errors before continuing. One way to do this is to change it to:

```
num.append(int(input()))
```

Since all the values in `num` are strings, `i % 3` tries to perform [old-string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples), which is not what you expect.